# Redirects aren't working in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to redirect on successful registration. I've knocked together this basic code to test out the principle:

```
app.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    if (user) {
        res.send(400);
    } else {
        var newUser = new User({ username: req.body.username, password: passwordHash.generate(req.body.password)});
        newUser.save();
        req.logIn(newUser, function(err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            return res.redirect('/my-events');
        })
    }
});
});
```

However, when this triggers, my browser sees a 302, followed by a successful GET of the page that the /my-events endpoint serves up...but no redirect.

What's wrong? Using res.redirect works when the browser is loading an endpoint, it just doesn't seem to work as the result of a $.post.

Comment: the 302 IS the redirect. What are you expecting? Also FYI in all cases (every branch in your control flow logic) must send a response of some kind. Your error handling looks like it will just fail to send any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you are using `$.post` for sending the data. If that is the case then server won't be able to redirect to the actual page. What you need to do is redirect the page manually yourself in the call back function of the post function like so.

```
 $.post('your endpoint',function(){

    window.location = 'page to redirect to';

 });
```

This should do it.

Comment: Ah. I didn't realize that was a restriction! I made the changes, and they were successful. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. God knows how many hours I have wasted with the same issue !